# Javascript touch library that still lets desktop events work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a javascript library that still allows normal events to work (mainly the scrollwheel). I'm working on an application that will be displayed on a TV screen and controlled by a Wii remote, but will also need it to work on desktop. I already have the page working for the desktop, now I'm just in search of a library that won't turn it completely into a touch controlled page. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of touch events are you looking for?  If scrolling try [iScroll4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mobile style scrolling on the desktop use [iScroll4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) by cubiq